# MyBatis Ignite L2 cache Integration does not work with Ignite 2.0

Tags: mybatis, ignite, spring-mybatis, mybatis-cdi

Following the steps mentioned at mybatis-ignite integration page @ [mybatis-ignite](http://www.mybatis.org/ignite-cache/) with Ignite 2.0, i see that the call to the mapper hangs & never returns. This is after working around several other issues like requiring ignite-cache configuration to be placed in IGNITE_HOME/config/default-config.xml which still doesn't get picked up unless i place it in a physical location in the project dir (otherwise i see the error in the log "Initializing the default cache. Consider properly configuring 'config/default-config.xml' instead.") which again also seems to have no effect.

Since the integration seems to have several issues i am not sure if it is still supported..any thoughts from any one who has successfully done this or from the mybatis-ignite team would be great.

Edit: If it helps, i have placed a small self contained project @ https://github.com/softwarebrahma/MyBatis-Ignite-L2-cache-POC that can be used to reproduce the issues i have mentioned.

I missed mentioning in the repo..but only the Ports table & schema is used for the purposes of the demo the other tables are not used. What happens is that in the file (github.com/softwarebrahma/MyBatis-Ignite-L2-cache-POC/blob/master/domain/src/main/java/com/brocade/dcm/domain/xml/PostsMapper.xml) if i remove the line "cache type="org.mybatis.caches.ignite.IgniteCacheAdapter" />" then everything will work fine without ignite caching. But the moment i add that line as shown in the uploaded file the mapper method calls just hangs.

Comment: If it helps i have placed a small self contained project @ https://github.com/softwarebrahma/MyBatis-Ignite-L2-cache-POC that can be used to reproduce the issues i have mentioned.

Comment: I missed mentioning in the repo..but only the Ports table & schema is used for the purposes of the demo the other tables are not used.

What happens is that in the file (https://github.com/softwarebrahma/MyBatis-Ignite-L2-cache-POC/blob/master/domain/src/main/java/com/brocade/dcm/domain/xml/PostsMapper.xml) if i remove the line "<cache type="org.mybatis.caches.ignite.IgniteCacheAdapter" />" then everything will work fine without ignite caching.

But the moment i add that line as shown in the uploaded file the mapper method calls just hang..

Comment: The question is being answered on Apache Ignite user list: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/MyBatis-Ignite-L2-cache-Integration-does-not-work-with-Ignite-2-0-td13126.html